# Problemas com Jquery Table!

Tags: jquery-datatables

Veja o código abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table_busca').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<form>
  <table class="table table-striped" id="table_busca">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th>Fontes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>09/02/2018</td>
        <td>CONTÁBIL - Regulamentação da RFB sobre o reconhecimento contábil de receitas</td>
        <td>Jota Info</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Eu estou seguindo esse vídeo abaixo:

[Dica da Semana #4 - Busca, filtragem, paginação e estilização rápida de Tabelas com o DataTables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHSM-fzW3P8)

Que correspondente a essa pagina:

[DataTables CDN](https://datatables.net/)

Porém o Jquery não está funcionando, alguém poderia dá uma olhada pra ver se alguém acha algo errado.

Comment: Para a galera te ajudar, é interessante colocar a solução no jsfiddle.net ou publicar uma página aberta que possamos simular a situação e ver os possíveis erros.

Comment: Coloca a importação do jquery antes as restantes: https://jsfiddle.net/pcmafg45/

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado

Comment: @wladyband pode responder? pra finalizar a pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi somente organizar da forma certas as importações

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```